# check database has correct structure

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I take the database url, user, password information from the user

```
Connection db = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
```

I will be performing operations on this database later, dynamically. Obviously I catch errors then too, but at my first connection to the database I would like to verify it has the correct tables and columns that I will be using (easier to throw an error at the start "this database is not set up correctly" rather than do lots of stuff, *then* find out the database is not set up correctly).

How can I verify this?

E.g. must check it has a structure with table names and column names and types like

```
create table user (
  username varchar(16) not null,
  primary key (username)
  );
create table foo (
  id int unsigned auto_increment not null,
  one int,
  two tinytext not null,
  three int
  );
```

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/jdbc/databasemetadata.html

Comment: Check out [`DatabaseMetaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) and search around for some examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To query tables and their columns in a database-agnostic way using JDBC, call [`conn.getMetaData()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getMetaData--).

Then use [`getTables(String catalog, String schemaPattern, String tableNamePattern, String\[\] types)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-) to query table information.

Use [`getColumns(String catalog, String schemaPattern, String tableNamePattern, String columnNamePattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) to query column information.

See javadoc of [`DatabaseMetaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) for other available methods.

Comment: Does this work if my user isn't root, and only has view access on some tables

Comment: @minseong Try it and see for yourself.